# jQuery problem referencing id - Using Howler.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I have a maze I'm struggling to sort:

I have this grid with 12 anchor tags

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  $("#minuetti").append(
    `<div class="col-6 col-md-3"> <a id="minuetto${i}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-1 minuetto">Minuetto ${i}</a></div>`
  );
}
```

Each one of those will play a different mp3 file with the code below using Howler.js.

```
$(".minuetto").on("click", function() {
  let id = this.id;
  let minuettoPath = `assets/music/${id}.mp3`;
  let cell = new Howl({
    src: [minuettoPath],
    onplay: function() {
      $(`#${id}`).text("Stop");
      $(".minuetto").addClass("disabled");
      $(`#${id}`).removeClass("disabled");
      $(`#${id}`).removeClass("minuetto");
      $(`#${id}`).on("click", function() {
        cell.stop();
      });
    },
    onend: function() {
      $(".minuetto").removeClass("disabled");
      $(`#${id}`).text(`Minuetto ${id.slice(8)}`);
      $(`#${id}`).addClass("minuetto");
      this.unload();
    }
  });
  cell.play();
});
```

My problem:

I'm trying to change the text of the button clicked and keep it enabled.
I'm disabling all remaining (11) buttons until the end of the mp3 file.
But when I click on the enabled button (the one playing) instead of stopping my mp3, it restarts.
What am I doing wrong with my jQuery here? I'm referencing to my id and calling the function to do `cell.stop()` but for some reason jQuery runs the playing again, even though I removed the class `minuetto` from the playing button.
I'm really puzzled. Please help?

Comment: PS: never append or construct DOM inside loops. Concatenate String or Arrays and append once - after the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, @RokoC.Buljan, I'll look into that. But this won't sort my struggle with jQuery and Howler. Anyway it's interesting what you said, I'm pretty new to this and would love to know how to achieve the same with a proper method. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use just `const sound = new Howl({src: mp3.path});`
- Create a element using jQuery's Object Element constuctor `$({})`
- Assign the needed events like `click()`, `play()`, and `stop()` that you can `trigger` when needed and perform your desired actions
- Use Howler's `sound.playing()` to determine which trigger callback is needed

```js
// Use an array of objects instead, otherwise if one day
// you decide to remove a numeric song you'll have to replace it with another.
// This also allows you to change the order of songs:
const mp3list = [
  {name:'Enter Sandman', path:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman.ogg'},
  {name:'Back in Black', path:'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg',},
  {name:'U2 - One', path:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/U2_One.ogg',},
];

let $allMP3 = [];

const $newMP3 = mp3 => {

  // HOWL
  const sound = new Howl({src: mp3.path});

  // $ ELEMENT
  return $('<div>', {
    class: 'minuetto',
    text: mp3.name,
    on: {
      click() {
        $allMP3.forEach($el => $el.not(this).trigger('stop'));
        $(this).trigger(sound.playing() ? 'stop' : 'play');
      },
      play() {
        $(this).text("Stop");
        sound.play();
      },
      stop() {
        $(this).text(mp3.name);
        sound.stop();
      }
    }
  });
};

$allMP3 = mp3list.map($newMP3); // Populate array of $ elements
$("#minuetti").append($allMP3); // Append once!
```

```html
<div id="minuetti"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.3/howler.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh this is just amazing! I realise how far I am from coming up with something like this!! Thanks so much! 
Your answer opens a world of possibilities but I have more questions than answers now :) 
First (and silly) question: How do I populate the DOM with this having each button inside its respective column?
Second: this is my work in progress project. I think (after your answer) that I'm doing it all wrong!! :( 
Any chance you could help me? It would be amazing!
Repo: https://github.com/GBrachetta/Musical-Dice
Live: https://gbrachetta.github.io/Musical-Dice/ (12 buttons not there still)

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta OK let me take a look at the code you got

Comment: This is the latest, attempting to have all 12 full pieces for preview. Eventually I plan to let the user choose from which ones of those to randomise:

https://github.com/GBrachetta/Musical-Dice/tree/develop

Comment: I was planning to use something like this to let the user create the string of letters to randomise:

`let letters = [];

$("input").change(function() {
  let selected = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    letters.push(selected);
  } else {
    letters.splice($.inArray(selected, letters), 1);
  }
  let choice = letters.join("");
  console.log(`choice: ${choice}`);
  // console.log(`letters: ${letters.sort()}`);
  let sorted = letters.sort().join(""); // Gives me a string with chosen letters ordered alphabetically
  console.log(`sorted: ${sorted}`);
});`

Comment: I also noticed that after calling randomise() a few times, then the sound of the individual cells in the grid gets totally distorted...

Comment: Yes, I have 12 minuetti, a to l

Comment: BTW hope the music is pleasant! I composed it :)